# The "My account" link will change to something personal when logging in (e.g. "account <username>")

Tags: php, wordpress, commerce

Currently, even after a customer has logged in using the "My Account" link in the menu (e.g. with Storefront), the text and link stays as it is. So customers do not easily see whether they are logged in or not already. There is no visual feedback. This is even more confusing if you come back later and are still logged in.

Other shopping sites like ebay or amazon change the "My Account" button to something personal (e.g. username) after the login has been done.

How can I adjust my link dynamically in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/).

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    <div class='my-account logged-in'>My Account</div>
} else {
    <div class='my-account'>My Account</div>
}
```

Then simply give the My Account button another color, or change the text to the users name.

Comment: if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    <div class='my-account logged-in'>My Account</div>
} else {
    <div class='my-account'>My Account</div>
}

Comment: I mean like this
for the "my account / login / register" page to be the user's first name, after the user has logged in,
thank you